# Use site web.config and not server web.config

Tags: iis, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I have a site and I want to use the web.config of my site and not the one from root web.config.

I'm trying to access to the ConnectionStrings located in the `web.config` of my site, but writing this line:

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
```

I access to the root web.config of the server and it has connectionString like:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

I also tried WebConfigurationManager, with the same results:

```
var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
```

What can I do to access my site's web.config and not the root one?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: do you have web.config located under you site deployed location with connectionString element? that should provide you site specific connection strings are you declared in it.

Comment: You can override the default ones by removing them via tags and adding yours via tags. However, your web.config must inherit other settings from the root web.config. That's by design.

Comment: @LexLi I tried removing the tags related to my site from the root web.config and I get the same ConnectionString. Debugging my code, I feel that I access to the root web.config and not to my web.config, because I get only one ConnectionString and I have two connectionStrings in my web.config.

Comment: You completely get it wrong. I did not ask you to remove the tags from root web.config. There are standard ways to override them, via proper tags in your web.config, http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, that was really useful for me to understand web.config inheritance and overrides, but what I need is to access to my web.config and not to the root web.config through code. That`s because I also need to access to other specific configurations that are in my web.config and not in the other one.

Comment: You get a collection from `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`, http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs,154 so if you override that properly, you will only see yours in web.config, not the root web.config, but if you don't override it properly you get the error. Rule of thumb.